# Nothing gets displayed when running a Qt QML project

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

I'm using Qt QML in Qt Creator, and nothing gets displayed when I run my `main.qml`:

`main.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 
import QtQuick.Window 
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard

Window {
    width: 100
    height: 100

    Rectangle {
        color: "red"
        anchors.fill: parent

    }
}
```

The output in the terminal:

```
11:22:25: Démarrage de C:\Users\azus\Documents\build-sans_titre2-Desktop_Qt_6_4_3_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\appsans_titre2.exe...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    width: 100
    height: 100
    Rectangle {
        color: "red"
        anchors.fill: parent

    }
    visible: true
}
```

This builds and shows a red window on Ubuntu 20.04, QT 5.12.12.  I have to specify the 2.12 on my system.

Answer (score 0):

`Window` needs to be set [visible](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-item.html#visible-prop), and you could do it this way:

```
import QtQuick 
import QtQuick.Window 
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard

Window {
    width: 100
    height: 100
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        color: "red"
        anchors.fill: parent

    }
}
```